# How to pass a react-transition-group TransitionComponent to react-bootstrap Toast?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-transition-group

I have the below custom `<CompleteToast/>` component built using `react-bootstrap`. I want to apply custom CSS transitions, but don't understand how to achieve this. The [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/toasts/#toast-props) say I should pass a custom `react-transition-group` `TransitionComponent` but don't expand on how or give an example.

I've tried looking at the default `<ToastFade/>` but don't understand Typescript. I've tried passing `<ToastTransition/>` as a reference but the children don't render (the reference works as "Exit animation complete!" is logged). Passing `<ToastTransition children={...}/>` causes errors.

What approach should I be taking here? Is this possible without TypeScript?

My instinct is that I need to figure out how `ToastTransition` can automatically inherit `Toast`'s children.

**CompleteToast.js**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Toast} from "react-bootstrap";
import {useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import {IoCheckmarkCircleOutline} from "react-icons/all";
import {GlobalAppContext} from "../../App";
import ToastTransition from "../react-transition-group/ToastTransition";

const dividers = {
    s: 1000,
    m: 60000,
    h: 3.6e+6,
    d: 8.64e+7,
    w: 6.048e+8,
    mo: 2.628e+9,
    y: 3.154e+10
}

const calculateTimeDiff = (timeInMs) => {
    const diff = Date.now() - timeInMs;
    switch (true) {
        case (diff < dividers.s):
            return "Just now";
        case (diff < dividers.m):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.s) + "s";
        case (diff < dividers.h):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.m) + "m";
        case (diff < dividers.d):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.h) + "h";
        case (diff < dividers.w):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.d) + "d";
        case (diff < dividers.mo):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.w) + "w";
        case (diff < dividers.y):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.mo) + "mo";
        case (diff >= dividers.y):
            return Math.floor(diff / dividers.y) + "y";
        default:
            return diff + "ms";
    }
}

const timeUntilNext = (from, unit = "s") => {
    let divider = dividers[unit];
    return (Math.ceil(from / divider) * divider) - from;
}

function CompleteToast({show, title, timestamp, bodyText, headerClass, updateDeleteIds, id, deleteIds}) {
    const [showState, setShowState] = useState(show);
    const [timestampUpdated, setTimestampUpdated] = useState(null);
    const [timestampState, setTimestampState] = useState(timestamp);
    const [timestampText, setTimestampText] = useState("Just now");
    const setToasts = useContext(GlobalAppContext)[0].setStateFunctions.toasts;
    const shownOnce = useRef(false);
    const deleteTimeout = useRef(null);
    const hovering = useRef(false);

    const close = () => {
        if (!hovering.current) {
            setShowState(false);
        }
    }

    const setDeleteTimeout = () => {
        if (shownOnce.current && !hovering.current) {
            deleteTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
                setToasts(prevState => prevState.filter(x => x.id !== id));
            }, 2000)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (showState) {
            setTimestampUpdated(Date.now());
            setTimestampState(Date.now);
        } else {
            setDeleteTimeout();
        }
    }, [showState]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!showState) {
            setShowState(true);
            shownOnce.current = true;
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (showState) {
            //timestamp has been updated and the toast is still showing - update the text to the current time difference
            const timeDiff = calculateTimeDiff(timestampState);
            setTimestampText(timeDiff);
            setTimeout(() => {
                //trigger new update to timestamp text on the next second
                setTimestampUpdated(Date.now());
            }, timeUntilNext(Date.now(), "s"));
        }
    }, [timestampUpdated]);

    return (
        <Toast style={{whiteSpace: "pre-wrap"}}
               onClose={close}
               onClick={close}
               onMouseEnter={() => {
                   hovering.current = true;
                   if (deleteTimeout.current) {
                       clearTimeout(deleteTimeout.current);
                       deleteTimeout.current = null;
                       setShowState(true);
                   }
               }}
               onMouseLeave={() => {
                   hovering.current = false;
                   setTimeout(close, 3000);
               }}
               show={showState}
               delay={4000}
               autohide
               id={id}
               transition={ToastTransition}
               className="cursor-pointer">
            <Toast.Header className={headerClass} closeButton={false}>
                <IoCheckmarkCircleOutline className={"smallIcon me-2"}/>
                <p className="fs-5 my-0 me-auto">{title}</p>
                <small>{timestampText}</small>
            </Toast.Header>
            <Toast.Body className={"position-relative"}>
                {bodyText}
            </Toast.Body>
        </Toast>
    );
}

CompleteToast.propTypes = {
    show: PropTypes.bool,
    handleClick: PropTypes.func,
    buttonText: PropTypes.string,
    buttonVariant: PropTypes.string,
    bodyText: PropTypes.string,
    headerClass: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string
};

CompleteToast.defaultProps = {
    show: false,
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    timestampText: Date.now(),
    title: "Success",
    bodyText: "The operation was completed successfully",
    headerClass: "bg-success text-white",
    buttonVariant: "primary"
}

export default CompleteToast;
```

**ToastTransition.js**

```
import {Transition} from 'react-transition-group';

//copied from react-transition-group docks - aim is to getit working, then customise the actual transition

const duration = 300;

const defaultStyle = {
    transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-out, maxHeight opacity ${duration}ms ease-out`,
    opacity: 0,
    maxHeight: 0,
}

const transitionStyles = {
    entering: {opacity: 1, maxHeight: "200px"},
    entered: {opacity: 1, maxHeight: "200px"},
    exiting: {opacity: 0, maxHeight: 0},
    exited: {opacity: 0, maxHeight: 0},
};

const ToastTransition = ({in: inProp, children}) => (
    <Transition
        in={inProp}
        timeout={duration}
        onExited={() => {
        console.log("Exit animation complete!")
    }}>
        {state => (
            <div style={{
                ...defaultStyle,
                ...transitionStyles[state]
            }}>
                {children}
            </div>
        )}
    </Transition>
);

export default ToastTransition;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot - it's as simple as calling the `children` prop which is 'special' and is passed automatically.

It was visually rendering because I needed to manually set a `show` class on the `<CompleteToast/>` component, i.e.:

```
className="cursor-pointer show"
```

The `react-transition-group` component handles the actual showing/hiding it seems (this is inconsistent with the default behaviour, but as far as I can see it's not cuasing issues so far).

**Working ToastTransition.js (need to tweak CSS)**

```
import {Transition} from 'react-transition-group';

const duration = 500;

const defaultStyle = {
    transition: `opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out, max-height ${duration}ms ease-out`,
    opacity: 0,
    maxHeight: 0
}

const transitionStyles = {
    entering: {opacity: 1, maxHeight: "200px"},
    entered: {opacity: 1, maxHeight: "200px"},
    exiting: {opacity: 0, maxHeight: 0},
    exited: {opacity: 0, maxHeight: 0},
};

const ToastTransition = ({in: inProp, children}) => {

    return (
        <Transition
            in={inProp}
            timeout={duration}
            onExited={() => {
                children.props.onExited();
            }}>
            {(state) => (
                <div style={{
                    ...defaultStyle,
                    ...transitionStyles[state]
                }}>
                    {children}
                </div>
            )}
        </Transition>
    )
}

export default ToastTransition;
```